# Problem authenticating GitHub account while installing Php on MacOS using Homebrew

Tags: php, ssh, homebrew, macos-monterey

I'm using macOS Monterey and trying to install Php using Homebrew. I read on several articles that installing through Homebrew is the simplest way to go about this on Mac. I'm following this tutorial : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-php-on-macos/

After successfully installing Homebrew, I use the command `brew tap username/php`

This is what I get on the terminal:

```
==> Tapping saadmohammad/php
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/saadmohammad/homebrew-php'...
Username for 'https://github.com': saad931549
Password for 'https://saad931549@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/saadmohammad/homebrew-php/'
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/saadmohammad/homebrew-php /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/saadmohammad/homebrew-php --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128.
```

How do you think I get past this?

I've managed to successfully set up an SSH key and add it to my GitHub account. Do you think I can use that to authenticate my account and continue with the installation? Clearly, I'm a beginner at this.

I have looked up articles on how to authenticate using an SSH key and they talk about a public and a private key. I can both the keys: public and private.

So, the problem boils down to being able to authenticate using an existing SSH key that has also been added to the GitHub account. I have tried to do that, so far without luck. And I'm unwilling to look into one of the articles out there as it may take far too long.

Can someone please point me out in the right direction? Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have checked your details but the saadmohammad on GitHub does not have the repositories of Homebrew/php so it is throwing error. If the repo found at https://github.com/saadmohammad/homebrew-php/ which is mentioned in the error response above then it worked well.

And its not brew tap username/php its actually the repo on GitHub. So use brew tap shivammathur/php and install the php from the command brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).